# VBA XLS Autofilter Criteria is Not equal to zero, but I'd like to test the result of a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to filter out all rows of a sheet where the result of column E (formula) is 0.  I think I'm close.  This sheet is the result of a pivot table on another sheet, and I want it to always take effect when the pivot is refreshed.  Right now, the scope of the question is to display where Not 0, on a formula.

```
Sub HideIfZero()
  Dim LastRow As Long

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Activate 
  ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

  With Worksheets("Results")
    .Range("$A:$G").AutoFilter
    .Range("$A:$G").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="<>0" 'this isn't working in the NOT select

    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    
  End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me (=0 rows are hidden by the filter), both with hard-coded values and formulae in column E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Sub HideIfZero()

    Dim PivotSht As Worksheet, WS As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, PT As PivotTable

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set PivotSht = .Sheets("ModifyMe") 'Modify to suit.
        Set WS = .ActiveSheet
    End With

    For Each PT In PivotSht.PivotTables
        PT.RefreshTable
    Next PT

    With WS
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A:G")
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>0"
        End With
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Debug.Print LastRow
    End With

End Sub
```

This will update all pivot tables in the proper sheet and apply a filter in the worksheet where you want the filter.

As mentioned by @andy holaday, this will work for both hard values and formula-calculated values that are equal to non-zero (your condition).

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: It's still now working for me, and perhaps it's because of the formula.  The formula is like this =(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA(specific stuff),0)).    Does GETPIVOTDATA or IFERROR mess up the comparison?  If I compare on a hard coded 0 it works great.  Thanks for your help.  I really have put a lot of effort into it before I asked.

Comment: What BK201 said is right.  In my instance, it sometimes works (or doesn't) because of decimals.  They look like zero but they've been rounded. So <>0 won't work.   Well, that answers that.  Thanks.